# how to do ".each()" when add an element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, element, addition, each

When I add an element of `type input=text` named `name="algumacoisa[number]"`.

I need to sum ​​the values ​​each time you add an extra field.
Using the `.each()` appears not work, because it not see the field `$('[name="algumacoisa[]"]').each()` to count how many fields there and sum their values​​.

Any idea?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: `$('[name="algumacoisa\\[\\]"]').each()`

Comment: Already did that, the problem is when I add a new field, .each() does not recognize the new field, only shows one value always ... never all they

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sum = 0;
$(':input[name^="algumacoisa"]').each(function(){
   var value = $.trim( this.value );
   if( $.isNumeric( value ) ) {
      sum += parseInt( value, 10 );
   }
});
```

About [$.isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/).

You can also use a function for this:

```
function getSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(':input[name^="algumacoisa"]').each(function() {
        var value = $.trim(this.value);
        if ($.isNumeric(value)) {
            sum += parseInt(value, 10);
        }
    });
    return sum;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YErc7/6/)**

[According to comment new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YErc7/8/).

Comment: Already did that, the problem is when I add a new field, .each() does not recognize the new field, only shows one value always ... never all they

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice $(':input....') must be why we did not have all the fields, now has. Thanks again.

Comment: @Daniel, note that this solution will only work with integers. If that's an issue, use `parseFloat` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This function will summ all field values, so long as the value can be interpreted as a number:

```
function sumFields() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type="text"][name^="algumacoisa"]').each(function(){
        var fieldVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
        if(!isNaN(fieldVal)) {
            total += fieldVal;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Each time you add a new field, run `sumFields()` (*after* the new field has been added to the DOM) which will return your total value

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:

```
var sum=0;
$('input[name^="algumacoisa["]').each(function(){
    sum += Number(this.value);            
});
alert(sum);
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/ceezt/)**

Comment: Already did that, the problem is when I add a new field, .each() does not recognize the new field, only shows one value always ... never all they